# Is this expression about density true?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, density

$$\frac{d \rho\ }{\rho} = -\alpha\ dT + \kappa\ dP $$
Where:

- $\rho\ $is density
- $\alpha\ $ is the coefficient of thermal expansion
- $\kappa\ $ is the coefficient of compressibility
- $T$ is temperature
- $P$ is pressure

Answer (score 0):

No.  There should be a minus sign in front of the first term on the right hand side and a plus term in front of the 2nd term.